# IMPDP Failing with ORA-00001: unique constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle

When I try to import a dump which contains data from several tables, the import fails with ORA-00001: unique constraint as there are several entries which are matching in the destination database, but there are several other values in the same table which are not getting imported due to unique constraint error.  I need those values.

Can some one help me out in solving this . I cannot use truncate / replace.

I have used this command:

```
impdp system/oracle@LIQ727DO directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=EXPDP_ACM_TABLES_LIQ72.DMP
  logfile=IMPDP_ACM_TABLES_LIQ72.log remap_schema=LIQ728:LIQ727 TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=append
```

Comment: Thanks Franek and Papp for your timely help , it worked i used data_options=skip_constraint_errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
impdp ... data_options=skip_constraint_errors
```

Above works only for non-deferred constraints though.

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16536/dp_import.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use " TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=append" knowingly?
If yes - try to remap during import to other schema which will be created automatically.
Then you can add privilege to query data from your current schema to the new one to get access to "other values".

If not - remove this flag.